# Grid and row height ( jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

So I have a problem with my grid. I'm using Isotope.js as grid plugin.

I got a request to do auto height of an element, but at the same time, all elements in that row are getting same new height.

Best way to explain is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1DMK.jpg

I'm taking any ideas.

2nd row of elements is same height as the 1st one, but then one element has more text than others, so all others in that row should be same height as the one that has more text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have had this problem in the past, I have decided on the height I want the boxes in the grid to be, and then specified that as the maximum height, and added `overflow: auto` in case the content doesn't fit.

```
.box {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I used `overflow-y` because you only want the scroll bar to be applied to the vertical side of the box, and auto so that the scroll bar is noly displayed when it is needed, not all the time.

**Using jQuery to set the height dynamically**

Alternatively, you could get the height of the tallest box in the row with jQuery and then set all the other boxes in the row to that height.

Some helpful person has already written a nifty script to do exactly that: https://pressupinc.com/blog/2014/02/setting-dynamic-equal-heights-multiple-elements-jquery/

Or you could use this jQuery plugin
http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/